# Add to Cart Not Working After Upgrade to 2.4.6.-p3

Tags: magento2, upgrade, session, cookie

after upgrading to Magento version 2.4.6-p3 ,
Add to cart not working,
it just shows adding and then nothing happens.
also when I go from category page with options products , it does not shows any error or success message for that.

I had tried all the solutions ,but nothing works,

please help me about this .

Comment: Hello, Has the same issue been resolved or are you still experiencing it?

Comment: @DeepakKumar solved , it was due to memcache , solved by server team

Comment: I'm glad to hear that the issue has been resolved. Thank you for letting me know.